# Asserts thrown in Test cannot be caught in TestFinished or RunFinished in nunit?

Tags: nunit

I have written a code to assert some values. I have also extended nunit so that 
    public void TestFinished(TestResult result){}

is run at the end of the test.

But, I am confused about its potential usefulness. I suppose the TestFinished method is used to write some helpful data about the test run.

But it seems there is no way to reference exceptions thrown by the Asserts in the TestFinished method.

Comment: What do you need `Exception` for? Do you need it to get Failure message?

Comment: Yes, wanted to catch the exception messages and log it in a database. If one of the eventlisteners can catch the assert exceptions then I can write the logging bit there. If not, I will have to call a logging function in each and every testcase.